# Match id with firebase element and get the the same element

Tags: angular

I am trying to get the element from firebase after passing the id from component i am using Angular 8

```
if (id) this.productService.get(id).subscribe(res => {
  this.table = res;
  console.log("Value from Firebase "+ JSON.stringify(this.table))  
})
```

This is my service component

```
get(tableid){
  return this.db.object('/table' + tableid).snapshotChanges();
}
```

This is my console output

```
Value from Firebase {"type":"value","payload":null,"key":null}
```

Comment: You are missing a slash `this.db.object('/table/' + tableid)`

Comment: Thanks Paul its working..

Comment: Now i am getting the result : Value from Firebase {"alphacode":"200","countryname":"America","currencyname":"Dollar","numericcode":9111}  let result = res.payload.val();
        this.table$ = JSON.stringify(result);   but when i am trying to bind it says TypeError: "ctx.result is undefined"

Comment: @PoulKruijt please help me to get access separate fields from {"alphacode":"200","countryname":"America","currencyname":"Dollar","numericcode":9111} in input  box